# Cannot disable Internet Sharing SSID

Tags: internet-sharing, lumia-925

I had previously enabled Internet Sharing on my Lumia 925 (Tmobile), but even when I toggle the option to Off to disable the feature, I still see the SSID for my phone in my Wifi list on devices such as my laptop or other phones.

How do I fully disable this? I tried switching the option to Bluetooth before disabling, but the Wifi ssid still remains active. I even renamed it just to make sure it was indeed my phone that was broadcasting, and yes indeed no matter what I do, I still see it.

Is this a known issue? I can't seem to find anyone else having it other than the exact opposite (where they can't ENABLE wifi sharing)...

please let me know what additional information I can provide that might be helpful

Comment: Did you set your laptop to remember the WiFi network? If so, try having your laptop "forget" the network, and then see if it still shows up.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a feature, not a bug. Your notebook recognizes that your phone is near and that you could start internet sharing without explicitly activating it on your phone. For this your phone Needs to be paired with your notebook through Bluetooth. As long as you're not connected to the phones Wi-Fi tethering will not be activated.

[Here's some more information on that topic](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/connectivity/share-my-connection), check out the "To connect on a Windows 8.1 tablet or laptop without entering a Wi-Fi Password" section. From my own tests (and seeing the question) you actually don't need to activate tethering for this to work.

Comment: wow that's actually pretty damn neat, where is this documented? Because how can it see the network if it is not broadcasting, and if it IS broadcasting, doesn't that mean it's draining my battery?

Comment: I did some mor digging - actually this only works when phone and notebooks are paired through Bluetooth. I updated the answer accordingly.